# Select data the the ID exists on another table in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have 2 tables, let says the first table named "Schedule" and the second named "Setting".

TABLE "SCHEDULE"

```
 ID    Name    StartTime    EndTime     Room  
---------------------------------------------
 111   AAAA    08:00        09:00       -
 112   BBBB    08:00        09:00       -
 113   CCCC    08:00        09:00       -
 114   DDDD    08:30        09:30       -
 115   EEEE    08:30        09:30       -   
 116   FFFF    08:30        09:30       -
```

TABLE "SETTING"

```
 ID    Type    Room  
------------------------
 111     1     BPD01  
 112     2     BPR33  
 113     2     BPR33  
 114     2     BPR35  
 115     2     BPR33
```

I want to get the result like:

```
 Room    StartTime  EndTime  Total Used   
---------------------------------------
 BPR33   08:00      09:00    2           
 BPR33   08:30      09:30    1           
 BPR35   08:30      09:30    1
```

I have the code like:

```
SELECT ST.Room, S.StartTime, S.EndTime, COUNT(*) AS [Total Used]
FROM Schedule AS S CROSS JOIN Setting AS ST
WHERE (ID IN
  (SELECT ID FROM Setting
   WHERE (Type = '2')))
GROUP BY ST.Room, S.StartTime, S.EndTime
```

But the code resulted in showing all of the record in Setting with the counted value, the filter does not run properly.

How to do that?

Comment: @OMGPonies: SQL Server..

Comment: Is there any reason for you to use the Schedule table here? It looks like you can get your results from just the Setting table.

Comment: @mathematical.coffee: I have edited my question. Yes, because there is a column that on the other table does not exists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see a few potential issues here:

- Your `WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM Setting WHERE Type='2')` looks like it could just be `WHERE Type='2'`
- What data type is your `Type` column? If it is INT, do `WHERE Type = 2` as opposed to `WHERE Type = '2'` (which you'd use if Type was VARCHAR).
- You do not appear to have a JOIN condition linking your two tables together (e.g. `WHERE S.ID = ST.ID`)

All together now:

```
SELECT ST.Room, S.StartTime, S.EndTime, COUNT(*) AS [Total Used]
FROM Schedule AS S CROSS JOIN Setting AS ST
WHERE S.ID = ST.ID 
AND Type = 2
GROUP BY ST.Room, S.StartTime, S.EndTime
```

Comment: Thanks, it's work :) . The data type for Type column is INT. And just like what you said, I forgot to have the join condition. :)

Comment: Why a CROSS JOIN and WHERE instead of a JOIN and ON?

Comment: Purely because that was what the OP used and I'm a MySQL person, and I wasn't sure if 'JOIN .. ON' (my preferred syntax) worked in SQL Server.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT ST.Room, S.StartTime, S.EndTime, COUNT(1) AS [Total Used]
FROM Setting AS ST
LEFT JOIN Schedule AS S 
ON S.ID = ST.ID
WHERE ST.Type = '2'
GROUP BY ST.Room, S.StartTime, S.EndTime
```

This shows the ones that were not scheduled with a zero count.  If you don't want that the join would change to:

```
SELECT ST.Room, S.StartTime, S.EndTime, COUNT(1) AS [Total Used]
FROM Setting AS ST
JOIN Schedule AS S 
ON S.ID = ST.ID
WHERE ST.Type = '2'
GROUP BY ST.Room, S.StartTime, S.EndTime
```

Comment: I was thinking something similar, but I can't work out why you need the join to Schedule. What does it add to the query?

Comment: @JBrooks: Thanks, I have figured out the problem :) . But why you stated Count(1) rather than Count(*)?

Comment: @mrjimoy_05 They result in the same and you should use Count(\*) because of SQL-92.  In the past Count(1) was a little more efficiency than Count(*) because it didn't have to hit the columns table.

Answer (score -1):

```
 SELECT ST.Room,Type AS [Total Used]
    FROM Schedule AS S CROSS JOIN Setting AS ST
    WHERE (ID IN
      (SELECT ID FROM Setting
       WHERE (Type = '2')))
    GROUP BY ST.Room
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: `Type` is not the same as `Total Used` in this case, being the `COUNT` for each unique `Room` (where `Type` == 2).